# Jquery/AJAX function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I already asked some questions about ajax, but I still don't get it.

I took a script that I found on the internet and made some modifications, but it didn't work!

**HTML:**

```
<a data-toggle="team" id="times">TEAM</a>
```

**ORIGINAL SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
    $(function() {
        $('nav a').click(function(e) {
            $("#loading").show();
            href = $(this).attr("href");

            loadContent(href);

            // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
            history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
            e.preventDefault();


        });

        // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            $("#loading").show();
            console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
            loadContent(location.pathname);
        };

    });

    function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $.getJSON("content.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
                // THIS LOOP PUTS ALL THE CONTENT INTO THE RIGHT PLACES
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $(key).html(value);
                });
                $("#loading").hide();
            });

        // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
        $('li').removeClass('current');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');

    }

</script>
```

**MODIFIED SCRIPT:**

```
<script>

// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
$(function() {
    $('#times').click(function(e) {
        $("#loading").show();
        var href = $(this).attr("data-toggle");

        loadContent(href);

        // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
        history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
        e.preventDefault();


    });

    // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        $("#loading").show();
        console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
        loadContent(location.pathname);
    };

});

function loadContent(url){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxcontdent/ajax'+url,
        type: 'GET',
        error: function(){
            // always good to have an error handler with AJAX
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }

        // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
        $('li').removeClass('current');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');

    };

</script>
```

What is wrong with my script? Nothing happens. I click in my `<a>` link and nothing. I already tried to put the file location on a `href`attribute, but then `e.preventDefault();` doesn't work and my website runs like there is no AJAX.

In the original code, the author use some `content.php` file. But I don't know JSON, so I have no idea what did he put in that file.

There are no errors in the console.

**My `ajaxcontent/ajaxteam.php` file content:**

```
<p style="color:#fafafa;">Team</p>
```

It's just one line indeed. Just a test.

Comment: What this script doing? What is your actual issue? do add expected output.

Comment: Nothing happens. I click in my `<a>` link and nothing. Unless I put file location on `href`attribute, but then AJAX don't work.

Comment: how is your `ajaxcontdent/ajaxteam` look like?

Comment: what errors do you have in console?

Comment: Do provide complete html. In your script code I can see `li` tag as well that showing error to me

Comment: @madalinivascu I added that informations to my topic.  

@PHPExpert The part about `li` in my code isn't working. It is not supposed to be. If I remove it from my script, I get the same result.

Comment: does your ajax call enter `.success` or `.error` block   ?

Comment: @dreamweiver none of them. When I click on my link nothing happens. Nothing, really.

Comment: try `dataType` as `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that may be a cause syntax error, I have regenerate one of your function so please use below code.

```
    function loadContent(url){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajaxcontdent/ajax'+url,
            type: 'GET',
            error: function(){
                // always good to have an error handler with AJAX
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#content').html(data);
            }
        });
    };
```

Then use your operation, whatever you want, in your success block of above function.

I hope thin will help you.

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

In your code if I am not wrong

`url: 'ajaxcontdent/ajax'+url,`

this is the main culprit.

Try this one:

`url: 'ajaxcontent/ajax'+url,`

Comment: Actually, I put it there to get an error, but it was not working. Anyway, it was a brackets and parentesis issue
Thank you, @devd c: